# Android ODK - How to store images in File server?

Tags: java, android, mysql, odk

I am developing the Data Collection Application using `ODK Framework` in Android. I just set up the `MySQL` server in my localhost and data is storing perfectly in `MySQL` Database. But the images are storing in binary Format. I want to store the images in image format(.jpg) in local directory. How can i acheive this? I searched and didnt found appropriate solution. Can anyone please help the way how to store the images in localhost in image format only by providing links...

Answer (score 0):

`ODK Aggregate` stores the images in the database so that aggregate can scale. Currently, there is no option of saving the images in a file system. Your best option is once all the data has been loaded onto the server, write a small script to download the images and save them.

You can use [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) as an option for downloading the images.

In `ODK Aggregate` there is an option to allow anonymous download of images, ensure that this option is checked.

My apologies no silver bullet link for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this with a python script. Here is a sample:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib
imageLink = "https://odkworkspace.appspot.com/view/binaryData?blobKey=BlahBlahBlah..."
outputFile = "c:/temp/test.jpg"
urllib.urlretrieve(imageLink, outputFile)
```

As another user mentioned, be sure that in ODK Aggregate you check the option to allow anonymous download of images.